# Insert and refresh pictures into word mail merge with python

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, mailmerge

I have a python script that uses win32.client and docx-mailmerge.
The current setup works fine with text based data, but I would like to work with pictures in the following way:

There's an excel that holds all the path to the pictures, I can use these in a mail merge, by creating an { INCLUDEPICTURE "<>" } field code with ctrl + F9.
The problem is that I have to press F9 every time to load in the correct data for the given image, else the same image will be shown on every page.
Is it possible to automate this refreshing process somehow from Python?
So if I start the merging it gets processed with the right pictures?

The relevant section from my code is here. As you can see I tried to use `doc.Content.Select` and `doc.Fields.Update`, however it did not work as the program just stopped at this point, without error.

```
        word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
        for i in range(0, len(data), step):
            
            document = MailMerge(path_docx)
            document.write("docs/" +output_file_name +"_-_" + ".docx")
            doc = word.Documents.Open("docs/" +output_file_name +"_-_" + ".docx")
            doc.Content.Select() #doc.Range(0,0) to get the whole document
            #update table of contents
            doc.Fields.Update()
            doc.Save()
            document = MailMerge(path_docx)
            if (start+step) < len(data):
                nextChunk = start + step
            else:
                nextChunk = len(data)
            temp = data[start:nextChunk]
            document.merge_templates(temp, separator='page_break')
            document.write("docs/" +output_file_name +"__"+ str(i) + ".docx")

            doc = word.Documents.Open(path+"/docs/" +output_file_name +"_"+ str(i) + ".docx")
            
            doc_name = path+"/docs/"+output_file_name+"_" + str(i) + ".pdf" if not template_only else path+"/docs/"+output_file_name+"_template_" + str(i) + ".pdf"
            doc.SaveAs(doc_name, FileFormat=17)
```